# Использование Android Numberpicker внутри ScrollView

Tags: android-sdk, activity, android

Нашел [готовую](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359510/android-number-picker-dialog) библиотеку (первый ответ) для использования `Numberpicker`, переделал её под себя, но когда я добавил в `ScrollView` ещё элементов, замел, что начал подтормаживать экран при прокручивании именно из-за него. Может кто сталкивался, из-за чего это происходит? Либа небольшая, можете посмотреть. Мне теперь необходимо свою view рисовать? Из-за стандартного тоже лагает, убираю их экран летает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в том, что все опробованные вами решения используют для своей реализации **ListView**. А **ScrollView** начинает неадекватно себя вести, если в него поместить элемент, могущий прокручиваться, т.е. тот же **ListView**, например.

Единственный вариант - продумать разметку так, чтобы **Numberpicker** не находился внутри **ScrollView**. Например вынести **Numberpicker** в диалог, вызываемый по кнопке из **ScrollView**.

Comment: Спасбо за ответ. Думаю будет нормально работать если создать свой Numberpicker унаследованный от View.

Comment: переделывать макет не хотелось бы

Comment: Да, если от View наследовать проблем быть не должно. Только вот реализовать сложно будет.